# How to make browser page search (Ctrl-F) start in specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a simple html layout with a nav div and content div. In some instances, the nav panel can have a lot of content.

When you use the default browser page search, Ctrl-F, the search begins in the nav div and may require several "next" clicks before the content panel is accessed (depending on the search term).

Is there any method of forcing the browser page search to start in a specific div?

Comment: What if the user wants to search your nav panel when it has "a lot of content"?  This is a browser UI behaviour, you shouldn't be trying to change it.  The user can select a bit of text to indicate where they want to start searching themselves if they want.  Perhaps you should look at introducing a custom search mechanism in your page?

Comment: The 'find' mechanism of a web browser searches the currently active document in its entirety. There is no method to restrict the area or elements where the search should take place. If you need that behaviour you would need to implement your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to create a selection with javascript...
Now, if you *`select`* some text and then *`search`* something with the *`find`* browser tool...
The *`search result`* must start from that point.
*<sup>(even if the results show all matches in the page, the first result starts where the user has the text selection)</sup>*

So, if we join this two.. we can have an approach of what you need...
something like:

```
$(window).on('keydown', function (event) {
    if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && (String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase() == 'f')) {
        if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById('search_from_here'));
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(document.getElementById('search_from_here'));
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        }
    }
});
```

Check this *jsFiddle* for an example http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/tdo7p1o5/
<sup>**Important!**: The focus must be on the "result iframe" for this example to work (in jsfiddle)</sup>

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't [TextRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextRange) IE-specific and non-standard? Anyway, there is [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range).

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to select a specific part of the page for the browser to search through when using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

The browsers search through the entire document it has loaded.

You could of course use JavaScript to to detect to press of both the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and the <kbd>F</kbd> key, and on that remove all data from the document, and only leave what you want them to search through. But that would neither be a good or a pretty solution considering that you would remove the most of your entire website, and the user would think something is broken.

Create a custom search field on your website instead.